# Inclusive intervals don't work as expected in jooq and postgres

Tags: postgresql, jooq

When using the jooq-postgres-extension and inserting a row with a field value `IntegerRange.integerRange(10, true, 20, true)` in the query it is translated by `cast('[10,20]' as int4range)`.

It's interesting that if I run the query `select cast('[10,20]' as int4range)` I get `[10,21)` which is not an inclusive interval anymore.

My problem is: when I read the row back in Jooq the `integerRange.end` is now 21 and not 20.

Is this a known issue and is there a workaround rather than the obvious subtracting 1 to upper boundary?

Comment: `[10,20]` is identical to `[10,21)`

Comment: No it isn't, doesn't have the same boundaries. It may produce the same result in queries but they are not the same. If your code need the upper boundary then it wont work unless you do the nasty hack of subtracting 1.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/jE2tWD6K

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying. It is equal for postgres but if the boundaries are part of the range identity it might not be equal. What if it is a tsrange would subtracting 1 also work? In the application side you'll end up add specific logic for every range type to get the correct upper boundary.

Comment: Shrug. This is the way it was designed and implemented. If you don't like it, the only thing you can do is change the Postgres code. The question is: why do you need that information? What is the underlying problem are you trying to solve with that? Why do you need to test for the boundaries at all? Why not include the information if the boundaries are inclusive or exclusive in that part of the test?

Comment: An alternative solution may be changing the jooq-postgres-extensions implementation or doing a custom extension or not using range types at all, which I am considering right now.

Comment: @PedroAlipio: You can't really change the jooq-postgres-extensions implementation in a meaningful way, because the information about the open/closedness of the discrete range is lost, and the two values are truly identical *within PostgreSQL*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jOOQ 3.17 [`RANGE` type support (#2968)](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2968) distinguishes between

- discrete ranges (e.g. `DateRange`, `IntegerRange`, `LongRange`, `LocaldateRange`)
- non-discrete ranges (e.g. `BigDecimalRange`, `LocalDateTimeRange`, `OffsetDateTimeRange`, `TimestampRange`)

Much like in PostgreSQL, jOOQ treats these as the same:

```sql
WITH r (a, b) AS (
  SELECT '[10,20]'::int4range, '[10,21)'::int4range
)  
SELECT a, b, a = b
FROM r;
```

The result being:

```
|a      |b      |?column?|
|-------|-------|--------|
|[10,21)|[10,21)|true    |
```

As you can see, PostgreSQL itself doesn't distinguish between the two identical ranges. While jOOQ maintains the information you give it, they're the same value in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL itself won't echo back `[10,20]::int4range` to jOOQ, so you wouldn't be able to maintain this value in jOOQ.

If you *need* the distinction, then why not use `BigDecimalRange` instead, which corresponds to `numrange` in PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH r (a, b) AS (
  SELECT '[10,20]'::numrange, '[10,21)'::numrange
)  
SELECT a, b, a = b
FROM r;
```

Now, you're getting:

```
|a      |b      |?column?|
|-------|-------|--------|
|[10,20]|[10,21)|false   |
```

Answer (score 2):

From here [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html):

> The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, [). User-defined range types can use other conventions, however.

So the `cast` transforms `'[10,20]'` to `'[10,21)'`.

You can do:

```
select upper_inc(cast('[10,20]' as int4range));
 upper_inc 
-----------
 f
```

to test the upper bound for inclusivity and modify:

```
select upper(cast('[10,20]' as int4range));
 upper 
-------
    21
```

accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it from the postgres side. I assume that jooq extensions should be aware of the canonical form and the conversion should take that under consideration then. It doesn't make sense to me expecting that this should be handled by the application and not by the library.

Comment: The same process happens with the Python library [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=range#psycopg2.extras.Range):                                                                                                                                                           `rs (1, NumericRange(10, 21, '[)')), rs[1].upper  21`. The libraries are just passing through the underlying behavior of the Postgres `range` type. I see that as a plus as the results match the documentation. It is up to the developer to work with the result.

Comment: Jooq is not a postgres library. I think passing an inclusive range when writing and getting an exclusive upper bound when reading doesn't seam very consistent. DSLs should not reproduce inconsistent underlying implementation details. Range boundaries shouldn't change. Especially when the DSL supports defining both options in each boundary. It makes even less sense to pass that inconsistency to the application.

Comment: @PedroAlipio: and how should jooq know that the range `[10,21)` was initially specified as `[10,20]` if all that is returned by the database is `[10,21)`

Comment: It may not be a Postgres library per se, but it supports Postgres specific features: [PG Specific types](https://twitter.com/javaooq/status/1499034556342669318) and [PG Range support](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2968).  The rules are laid out here [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) *8.17.7. Discrete Range Types*. You may not like them, but that is what you have to work with.

Comment: @PedroAlipio: *"Jooq is not a postgres library"* - This particular extension was written for PostgreSQL only. It is not a part of the core jOOQ library, and it is not being emulated in any other RDBMS. There is really no good reason for this extension to pretend PostgreSQL doesn't behave exactly the way it does. It can't "fix" PostgreSQL.